# How to get Button in a DataGrid in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, button, datagrid

I have a datagrid that has buttons in some rows.I need to reach that button in my page_loaded eventlistener because i need to change enabling of this buttons.

How can i reach Button objects in datagrid?

Comment: can you try this:<Button IsEnabled="{Binding isbtnEnabled}"/>, and the button will be enabled/disabled by your isBtnEnabled.

Comment: nope,i tried but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to enable/disable buttons on page load?

Why not enable/disable them in the xaml?

```
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyButtonCol">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Button" Click="MyButton_Click" IsEnabled="false"  Name="MyButton" Cursor="Hand" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

---- edit-----

Bind your visibility to the property that you have in your code behind

```
Visibility="{Binding YourVisibilityProperty}"
```

Comment: I need to disable the button dynamically according to data.

Comment: My page has a property that change the buttons enabling.

Comment: Ah i see - see my edit. if this doesnt work, it may help for you to post your property code that disable/enable the buttons

Comment: Sorry,didn't work.But I deleted the button column instead.Thanks for help :)